# Cardápio Lanchonete

Tags: python

Saudações, sou iniciante em python e preciso fazer um código em que o mesmo inicie com um tabela, informando o produto, seu valor e um código para o mesmo. O programa tem que solicitar o código de um produto, a quantidade desejada e devolver o valor vezes a quantidade que foi solicitada... Fiz diversos testes, em um ele não aceitava nada, no outro, não importava os valores colocados, o programa me devolvia zero, e na minha ultima tentativa, o programa solicita infinitamente o código e a quantidade, desde já agradeço

````
print('================================= \n| COD |     PRODUTO     | VALOR | \n| 100 | Cachorro quente | 1,20R$| \n'
      '| 101 | Bauru Simples   | 1,30R$|\n| 102 | Bauru com ovo   | 1,50R$|\n| 103 | Hamburguer      | 1,20R$| \n'
      '| 104 | Chessburguer    | 1,70R$|\n| 105 | Suco            | 2,20R$| \n| 106 | Refrigerante    | 1,00R$|\n'
      '=================================\n Para sair digite 999')
total = 0
while True:
    q = int(input('Informe o codigo: '))
    if(q == 999):
        break
    qtd = int(input('Informe a quantidade: '))
    if q == 100:
        total = 1.20 * q
    elif q == 101:
        total = 1.30 * q
    elif q == 102:
        total = 1.50 * q
    elif q == 103:
        total = 1.20 * q
    elif q == 104:
        total = 1.70 * q
    elif q == 105:
        total = 2.20 * q
    elif q == 106:
        total = 1 * q
    else:
        print('Codigo invalido')
print(total, 'reais') ```
````

Comment: faz um if q c na variavel `q` vier um valor por ex -1 vc da um break no while. pra assim poder ir para o print final

Comment: Em todas as contas, você está multiplicando pelo `q` (código) e deveria multiplicar pelo `qtd` (quantidade). Além disso, faça `total += <sua conta aqui>`. Fora isso, o código parece OK.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

respondendo a sua pergunta, o seu erro está na endentação do código, onde está mandando printar o valor do pedido está fora do laço do `while True:` assim nunca o executando,
outra coisa que pude perceber é que você esta multiplicando o valo do produto pelo código e não pela quantidade onde acredito que seria o certo,

fiz umas alterações para exemplificar o que falei espero que te ajude.

```
a = ('================================= \n| COD |     PRODUTO     | VALOR | \n| 100 | Cachorro quente | 1,20R$| \n'
  '| 101 | Bauru Simples   | 1,30R$|\n| 102 | Bauru com ovo   | 1,50R$|\n| 103 | Hamburguer      | 1,20R$| \n'
  '| 104 | Chessburguer    | 1,70R$|\n| 105 | Suco            | 2,20R$| \n| 106 | Refrigerante    | 1,00R$|\n'
  '=================================\n Para sair digite 999')
total = 0

while True:

    print(a)

   q = int(input('Informe o codigo: '))
    if(q == 999):
        break
    qtd = int(input('Informe a quantidade: '))
    if q == 100:
       total = 1.20 * qtd
    elif q == 101:
        total = 1.30 * qtd
    elif q == 102:
        total = 1.50 * qtd
    elif q == 103:
        total = 1.20 * qtd
    elif q == 104:
        total = 1.70 * qtd
    elif q == 105:
        total = 2.20 * qtd
    elif q == 106:
         total = 1 * qtd
    else:
        print('Codigo invalido')

    print('o Seu total foi ->', total, 'reais')

    b = input('deseja continuar: ')

    if b == 'sim':
       pass

    else:
       break
```

nesse caso alterei apenas a variável que estava multiplicando o valor, inseri o `print` dentro do laço do `while True:` e adicionei uma verificação para encerrar o código caso não seja mais usado

Answer (score -4):

O utilizei o dicionário, uma estrutura de dados que é bastante útil e utiliza o par chave-valor. Acredito que trabalhar assim fica mais natural.

```
print('================================= \n| COD |     PRODUTO     | VALOR | \n| 100 | Cachorro quente | 1,20R$| \n'
      '| 101 | Bauru Simples   | 1,30R$|\n| 102 | Bauru com ovo   | 1,50R$|\n| 103 | Hamburguer      | 1,20R$| \n'
      '| 104 | Chessburguer    | 1,70R$|\n| 105 | Suco            | 2,20R$| \n| 106 | Refrigerante    | 1,00R$|\n'
      '=================================\n Para sair digite 0')

menu = {

    '100': ['Cachorro quente', 1.20],
    '101': ['Bauru Simples', 1.30],
    '102': ['Bauru com ovo', 1.50],
    '103': ['Hamburguer', 1.20],
    '104': ['Chessburguer', 1.70],
    '105': ['Suco', 2.20],
    '106': ['Refrigerante', 1.00]
}

pedido = {}
while True:
    codigo = input('Informe o codigo: ')
    if (codigo == '0'):
        break
    if codigo in menu:
        quantidade = int(input('Informe a quantidade: '))
        if quantidade > 0:
            valorItem = menu.get(codigo)
            pedido.update({codigo: (valorItem, quantidade)})

valorDoPedido = 0

for linha in pedido.items():
    valorDoPedido += linha[1][0][1] * linha[1][1]  # Preço * Quantidade

print('\nSEU PEDIDO: ')

for linha in pedido.items():
    print(str(linha[1][1]) + ' x ' + 'R$ ' + str(round(linha[1][0][1], 2)) + ' --- ' + str(linha[1][0][0]))

print('\nTOTAL DO PEDIDO: R$ ' + str(round(valorDoPedido, 2)))
```